Change Axes of legend in Matplotlib
I have a figure with some inset axes at variable positions. Each of these inset axes has the same lines and thus the same legend.
To avoid cluttering the figure, I would like to only show the legend of one of these insets and position it (for example) in the top right corner of the main ax to indicate that this is a general legend.
This is a simplified version of my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(range(10), range(10))

inset_ax1 = inset_axes(ax,
                       width=1.5,
                       height=1.5,
                       loc='lower right')

inset_ax2 = inset_axes(ax,
                       width=2,                             
                       height=2,                         
                       loc='upper left')

inset_ax1.plot(range(10), np.random.rand(10,3))
inset_ax2.plot(range(10), np.random.rand(10,3))
inset_ax1.legend(['a', 'b', 'c'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()

I tried using ax.add_artist(inset_ax1.legend()) but this gives the following warning: ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported. How can i resolve this?
To give some context: I'm making a figure similar to this but I would like to show a single legend for all the windroses. The position and number of insets is variable.

If you get hold of the lines from one of the insets, you can pass these to a legend on your main axes.  Note that this will override legend's automatic detection of any artists on your main axes.
lines1 = inset_ax1.plot(range(10), np.random.rand(10,3))
lines2 = inset_ax2.plot(range(10), np.random.rand(10,3))

ax.legend(lines1, ['a', 'b', 'c'], loc='upper right')



I tried this as well, but the plotting function which I'm using (windrose's contourf) returns None so this does not seem to work.

I found windrose's logic for determining its legend handles is here.  I guess you could copy that into your own code and use the return value of get_handles in place of lines1 above.
